# How to interpret variable assignment shown as below used in python?

Tags: python

what does below code snippet initialization indicates ? how does it work ? how this variable assignment operates in python ?

```
  def set_action_delays(
        self,
        enabled: bool = False,
        like: int = None,
        comment: int = None,
        follow: int = None,
        unfollow: int = None,
        story: int = None,
        randomize: bool = False,
        random_range_from: int = None,
        random_range_to: int = None,
        safety_match: bool = True,
    ):
```

Comment: is your question about the *default arguments* or about the *type hints*?

Comment: i didn't understand the way ***type hints*** are used

Comment: Got it from below answer. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are default parameter values:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_default_parameter.asp

For instance, looking at `safety_match: bool = True`: the default value would be set to `True` in the case that the function is called without the argument.

The `int`, `bool`, etc are type hints:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html

Comment: Okay Got it, Thank You @costaparas

Answer (score 0):

These are "key arguments" also called "named arguments". If you are more familiar with other languages, where there are only "positional arguments" this def call would have same effect as your code, ie. **you can use named on positioned arguments in python**:

```
  set_action_delays(self, False, None, None, None, None, None, False, None, None, True)
```